# Go: Define multidimensional array with existing array's type and values?

Tags: arrays, go, multidimensional-array

Is it possible to a)define b)initialize a new multidimensional array using an existing array, like in following code instead of `var b [2][3]int`, just saying something like `var b [2]a` ?
Using a's type whatever it is, instead of hardcoding it (which misses the point of using [...] for a).
And perhaps handling initialization=copying of values at the same time?

```
package main

func main () {
        a := [...]int{4,5,6}
        var b [2][3]int
        b[0],b[1] = a,a 
}
```

(I'm aware of ease and convenience of slices, but this question is about understanding arrays.)

Edit: can't believe I forgot about `var b [2][len(a)]int`, beginner's brain freeze. One line answer would be `var b = [2][len(a)]int{a,a}` . That's a type  conversion, right?

Comment: maybe Templates since they can support any type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code would also work. Both your example and mine do the same thing and neither should be much faster than the other.

Unless you use reflect to make a slice (not array) of your `[3]int`, it is impossible to not repeat `[3]int` in your new type. Even that is not possible in the current release. It is in tip and will be released in Go 1.1.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := [...]int{4,5,6}
    var b = [2][3]int{a, a}
    fmt.Println(b)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I also seem to have a beginner's brain freeze, as `var b [2][len(a)]int` seems to work just fine.

Comment: Yes, `len(array)` is a constant expression (calculated at compile time) and therefore can be used when defining other array types.